# Sqoop - how to use a pseudo column for Split By

Tags: hadoop, db2, sqoop

I am using Sqoop to pull data from DB2.
Is there a way to use a column calculated on the fly as Split By in Sqoop command? For ex: if I calculate row_number() as part of my Sqoop query and I want to use that as Split By:

```
sqoop import -m 40 --boundary-query "select 1, count(*) from tablename" --query "select t.*, row_number() over(ORDER BY columnname) had_key from tablename  t WHERE \$CONDITIONS" --split-by had_key
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-968, SQLSTATE=57011, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.14.88
```

Comment: I changed the query to `"select * from (select t.*, row_number() over(ORDER BY columnname) had_key from tablename  t) WHERE \$CONDITIONS"`
And I removed the -m switch. It seems to be working now, however it is using default 4 mappers. It seems the previous error is related to issue on DB resources as I had used 40 mappers. I guess I need to look into the resources available on DB2 for the account I am using to connect.

Comment: [SQLCODE -968 means](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00968c.html?lang=en) one (or more) of the filesystems on the server is full.

Comment: thanks, I have to work with DBAs and find out the tablespace available and accordingly determine the correct number of mappers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, sqoop uses calculated columns to partition the source table. It has to be a physical column.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying different things so the error in my original question was for another scenario.
When I had the query as

```
--boundary-query "select 1, count(*) from tablename" --query "select t.*, row_number() over(ORDER BY columnname) had_key from tablename t WHERE \$CONDITIONS" --split-by had_key
```

the error was

```
Error: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=HAD_KEY, DRIVER=4.14.88
```

The cause of this error is it was unable to find HAD_KEY column. 
When I changed the query as below and leave the default mappers to 4

```
"select * from (select t.*, row_number() over(ORDER BY columnname) had_key from tablename t) WHERE \$CONDITIONS"
```

the issue is resolved and I am able to successfully use calculated column HAD_KEY for the splits. If I use 40 mappers with the above query, it was throwing the tablespace error

```
Error: java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-968, SQLSTATE=57011, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.14.88
```

so I just need to determine the correct number of mappers based on the resources available on the source DB